# How to prevent crashing my 64bit VBA application when opening a workbook containing 32bit VBA code

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am writing a VBA application to preprocess excel files that I receive periodically from a client. These files contain 32 bit VBA code (which I don't care about), and I am running Excel 64bit.

When my macro opens the input file it crashes because the client's code is not 64bit compliant.
I tried opening the workbook wrapped in 'disableEvents' without succes.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
wb_input = Workbooks.Open(fpfn_input)
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I googled but did not find an exact solution that does not involve me fixing the clients file/code. The client is not receptive to changing their file whatsoever.

Anyone know how to open an these files whilst ignoring the associated VBA code?

Comment: `When my macro opens the input file it crashes because the client's code is not 64bit compliant` .. how do you know that this is the reason?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638867/vba-excel-try-catch for exception handling.

Comment: When my VBA code tries to 'close' these workbooks containing 32bit code I get the message: "Compile error: the code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update declare statements and then mark them with the ptrSafe attribute". On my 32bit machine it runs smoothly but that machine is slow. I did manage to get the code to move past these messages but I cannot prevent the this messagebox from popping up.